# Can't remember the name of this card game

Tags: identify-this-game, rummy, solitaire

There was a game we played a few years ago... a friend taught us but can't remember how to play! I remember we named it "Slummy" because it was a cross between rummy and solitaire (and we didn't know the name). I know there were cards on the table as well as in your hand and it was played with 2 decks. You can play with 2 or 3 people (maybe more.. don't know) I have searched everywhere, and spent hours looking. I also bought a card game book trying to find it.

HOPEFULLY someone will know. It's driving me nuts!

Comment: Any other details you can share?  A 2 deck game that is a mix of rummy and solitaire isn't much to go on.

Comment: hard to remember... we were all drinking all weekend! lol I know it had cards down... like solitaire, and cards in your hand.. I think you could play on each others cards. But thats all i remember.  I cant find ANY card games that are a mix of both.   Picture dbl solitaire, but holding hands as well :)

Comment: In some versions of asian rummy, you can lay down some of your sets or runs. These sets/runs are much different than Klondike Solitaire alternating suit runs. Are you sure the game plays like solitaire, In what way? Check 2+ player card games http://www.pagat.com/number/2_players.html

Comment: nope, ive looked through all those... it plays like solitaire in the way that you have some cards down in front of you... then in between players you build on the stacks (A-K... or maybe something about the kings first??)

Comment: Is it anything like Slam or Ligretto? http://boardgames.about.com/od/spit/a/spit_rules.htm http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ligretto

Comment: its not spit... i know that one.  Parts of Ligretto sound familiar, but we did not use special cards.  Thanks evryone for trying to help!

Comment: Sounds a bit like "Sevens" in which the sevens start on the table and players take it in turns to play cards onto the runs, building up or down. I don't remember the specific rules though!

Comment: Did each player have a deck, or was it two decks no matter how many people were playing?

Comment: 2 decks for 2 or 3 people (we never played with more)

Comment: @GeoffGoldsmith, **King's Corner** is played with a single deck, with community piles, Kings start the piles and is kind of like solitaire. http://www.members.shaw.ca/bvwhit/kings.html

Comment: What was the goal of the game? Was play simultaneous or turn-based?

Comment: @PatLudwig: I have voted to close this question as being too localized. It seems like an "invented," not established game, that only a few people would know how to play.

Answer (score 1):

From the information given, this sounds a lot like the game [Speed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_%28card_game%29), but speed doesn't need to be played with 2 decks.

Answer (score 1):

The way rummy figures in doesn't seem very clear from your description. It sounds similar to [Pounce](http://www.pagat.com/patience/pounce.html); in that game you have a personal tableau, common piles of cards that you're building on, and a bunch of cards you hold--although it's a stack, not a hand.

If you remember the objective of your game, that would be helpful.

Comment: This would be my guess too